# deploying chat application on web server

Tags: java, apache, chat

I have build one chat application, which consists of server and client part & backend uses sql server 2005. Now i want to deploy my chat app on Apache web server. by converting it to exe and allow users an option to download my exe file through jsp file.

Now what i need to know is:

1. What exactly i need to convert in exe(is it server or client or both seperately).
2. Can my chat application automatically access database if i convert it into exe.
3. Do i need to deploy both client and server exe  on web server.

I hope i am clear enough.

Comment: This question is bit broad, I've no idea what you've built so far. Do you want to deploy a fat client (.exe)? Is it a Java application on the server-side, if so you should use a servlet engine like tomcat and not just Apache HTTP Server (you know the difference?)? You must provide more details!

Comment: @home so far, i have made client and server code,(using swings) for chat communication between multiple users. now  i want to create an exe file first and then give users and option to download this file(mainly through jsp).

Comment: So you should do some research on how to create an `exe` out of client Java code (not sure if this is possible at all). IMO, Swing on the server-side does not make sense at all...

Comment: You should take some time and understand your architecture... Regarding the JSP: place it in a WAR file and deploy the WAR into a servlet container like Tomcat, JBoss, etc.

Comment: @home ok one last question how to create war file of my jsp file

Comment: Use an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans - that's the easiest way

Comment: @home but it creates jar file, is war file same as jar file